# Soft Input Panel registry on Window CE7

Tags: registry, windows-ce

I want to dock the SIP on Windows CE7, and there is a registry to do that which is DragStyle in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\SIP.  After I set DragStyle to 0, the SIP does not display correctly.  When I switch between SIP, there is white layout around the SIP like it's not transparent.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

thanks.

Comment: That's the behavior of a docked SIP

Comment: Really that is normal behavior of docked SIP, but when on CE6 and modifying that same registry, it works perfectly.  There is no white layout attached to the SIP itself.  On CE7, that white layout makes me think that people forgot to crop out the image from background in Photoshop or something..